# Django-shop first migration problems

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-shop

Installing all correctly step by step using django-shop tutorial. When i try to make migrations i get an error. Help me fix it please.

```
(shoptutorial) debserv@debian:~/Desktop/project/django-shop/example$ ./manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/debserv/Desktop/project/shoptutorial/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/    management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/debserv/Desktop/project/shoptutorial/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/    management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/debserv/Desktop/project/shoptutorial/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line     18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/debserv/Desktop/project/shoptutorial/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",     line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/debserv/Desktop/project/shoptutorial/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",     line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/debserv/Desktop/project/shoptutorial/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in     import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/debserv/Desktop/project/django-shop/example/myshop/models/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from shop.models.defaults.cart import Cart
  File "/home/debserv/Desktop/project/django-shop/shop/models/defaults/cart.py", line 5, in <module>
    from shop.models.cart import BaseCart
  File "/home/debserv/Desktop/project/django-shop/shop/models/cart.py", line 12, in <module>
    from shop.money import Money
  File "/home/debserv/Desktop/project/django-shop/shop/money/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from money_maker import MoneyMaker, AbstractMoney
ImportError: No module named 'money_maker'
```

Comment: is money_maker a file in your app? if yes please post your directory structure. If not please reference where money_maker came from

Comment: it came from /project/django-shop/shop/money/money_maker.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your `django-shop/shop/money/__init__.py`
rather than

```
from money_maker import MoneyMaker, AbstractMoney
```

you should either:

```
 import .money_maker import MoneyMaker, AbstractMoney
```

or

```
 import shop.money.money_maker import MoneyMaker, AbstractMoney
```